# Weird Bug in my Javascript Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, scope, v8

I Have run across a weird bug, where an exported function completely ignores the passed parameter and instead generates its own parameter.

My code is as follows:

```
exports.returnThumbs = function(req, res) {
    var params = '{}, {thumb: 1}';
    console.log(params);
    PictureService.find(params, function(err, response){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            res.send(response, 'binary');
        }
    });
}
```

Which calls:

```
// Finds Answer by Passed Parameters
exports.find = function(params, callback){
    console.log(params);
    PictureModel.find(params, function(err, response){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            callback({'error': 'Error retrieving answers'});
        } else{
            if(!response){
               callback({'error': 'There are no pictures from this user_id'});
            } else{
               callback(null, response); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this should clearly pass '{}, {thumb: 1}' as the parameter, but the console.log instead prints:  { user_id: 'thumbnails' }   which is very weird.  No matter what I do, renaming, refactoring. it always prints this as a parameter.

Comment: what does your console.log(response); prints?

Comment: You are using some other `find` ??

Answer (score 0):

I ended up tracing it back to my router. I was parsing the request inappropriately.